# IFTTT custom android notification sound

Tags: sms, notifications, custom-sounds, ifttt

I added a recipe that sends notifications to the IFTTT app on my android device. Right now the notification sound is the same as for an incoming SMS. Is there a way to either change the IFTTT notification sound, all notification sounds, or just the SMS sound (Galaxy S4, Android 5.0.1) ?

Answer (score 1):

No obvious way at this time. This feature has been requested for (literally) years without resolution.

https://twitter.com/ifttt/status/631963245750845440?lang=en